# How do I implement tenant-based routing for elasticsearch in JHipster?

Tags: elasticsearch, microservices, jhipster, multi-tenant, spring-data-elasticsearch

I´m currently trying to implement multi-tenancy into my JHipster microservices. However, I can't find a way to implement tenant-based routing for elasticsearch.

So far I have managed to implement datasource routing for the PostgreSQL DBs similar to the following article: https://websparrow.org/spring/spring-boot-dynamic-datasource-routing-using-abstractroutingdatasource

When I started looking for ways to implement multi tenancy in elasticsearch, I found the following article: https://techblog.bozho.net/elasticsearch-multitenancy-with-routing/

There I read about tenant-based routing. First I tried looking it up on the internet, but anything I found was either over 5 years old or not related to java, much less to Spring/Jhipster. Then I tried looking into the methods of ElasticSearchTemplate, the annotation variables of @Document and @Settings and the configuration options in the .yml file, but didn't find anything useful.

I'm currently using Jhipster version 7.9.3, which uses the Spring-Boot version 2.7.3. All the microservices were created with JDL and on half of them I put elasticsearch into the configuration. The other half does not matter.

Edit: I want to add that multi-tenancy in my database is archived by database separation(Tenant1 uses DB1, Tenant2 uses DB2 etc.). The tenant variable is an enum and not included in my entities.

Edit2: I implemented my own solution. I use the tenants as indexes and use my ContextHolder from DataSource Routing to route to the correct tenant index. For that I had to do some changes the elasticsearchTemplate in the generated classes of the package "<my.package.name>.repository.search".

It might not be the most efficient way to reach multi tenancy with elasticsearch, but it doesn't need much configuration.

Here is the code:

```
public interface ProductSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Product, Long>, ProductSearchRepositoryInternal {}

interface ProductSearchRepositoryInternal {
    Stream<Product> search(String query);

    Stream<Product> search(Query query);

    void index(Product entity);
}

class ProductSearchRepositoryInternalImpl implements ProductSearchRepositoryInternal {

    private final ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;
    private final ProductRepository repository;

    ProductSearchRepositoryInternalImpl(ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchTemplate, ProductRepository repository) {
        this.elasticsearchTemplate = elasticsearchTemplate;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<Product> search(String query) {
        NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = new NativeSearchQuery(queryStringQuery(query));
        return search(nativeSearchQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<Product> search(Query query) {
        return elasticsearchTemplate.search(query, Product.class, IndexCoordinates.of(TenantContextHolder.getTenantContext().getTenant())).map(SearchHit::getContent).stream();
    }

    @Override
    public void index(Product entity) {
        repository.findById(entity.getId()).ifPresent(t -> elasticsearchTemplate.save(t, IndexCoordinates.of(TenantContextHolder.getTenantContext().getTenant())));
    }
}
```

Edit3: Since people might not know where ".getTenant()" comes from, I'll show my tenant enumeration:

```
public enum Tenant {
    TENANTA("tenant_a"),
    TENANTB("tenant_b");
    String tenant;
    
    Tenant(String name) {
        this.tenant=name;
    }
    public String getTenant() {
        return this.tenant;
    }
}
```

Edit4: My solution is not working as planned. I will give an update once I found a better and more robust solution.

Edit5: I have found out how to implement tenant-based routing. First you have to add the following Annotation to your entities:

```
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Routing(value = "tenant")
```

In my case I had to include the enum "Tenant" into my entities along with the getter and setter:

```
@Transient
private Tenant tenant;

public Tenant getTenant() {
    return tenant;
}

public void setTenant(Tenant tenant) {
    this.tenant = tenant;
}
```

Then I have to set the tenant during the processing of a REST request before it gets indexed by elasticsearchtemplate:

```
entity.setTenant(TenantContextHolder.getTenantContext());
```

As for the search function, I had to add a term query as a filter to enable routing:

```
@Override
public Stream<Product> search(String query) {
    
    NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = new NativeSearchQuery(queryStringQuery(query)
            , QueryBuilders.termQuery("_routing", TenantContextHolder.getTenantContext()));
    return search(nativeSearchQuery);
}
```

The method "setRoute(String route)" of "nativeSearchQuery" either does not work in my case or I didn't understand how it works.

I have successfully tested this implementation with GET and POST requests. Currently I have a problem with elasticsearch overwriting data if the id of the entity from one tenant I want to save is the same id as another entity with a different tenant.

Comment: By routing I suppose you mean one index per tenant. This is the most expensive option. You could also use a shared index by passing tenant id as a field to your index. Also remember that you don,'t have to do all in java, you can implement your tenant isolation using ES ingest pipeline. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html

Comment: If you found a solution, you should have written it as an answer not as a question edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found a solution to the overwriting problem and successfully completed and tested my implementation of tenant-based routing. Here is the code:

Product.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;

@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)


@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "product")
@SuppressWarnings("common-java:DuplicatedBlocks")
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Routing(value = "tenant")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Transient
    private Tenant tenant;
    
    @Transient
    @Field(name = "elastic_id")
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
    private String elasticsearchId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
"sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")    
    @Field("postgres_id")
    private Long id;
//Getters, Setters and other variables
}
```

ProductSearchRepository

```
public interface ProductSearchRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Product, Long>, ProductSearchRepositoryInternal {}

interface ProductSearchRepositoryInternal {
    Stream<Product> search(String query);

    Stream<Product> search(Query query);

    void index(Product entity);
    
    Product save(Product entity);
    
    void deleteById(Long id);
}
@Transactional
class ProductSearchRepositoryInternalImpl implements ProductSearchRepositoryInternal {

    private final ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;
    private final ProductRepository repository;

    ProductSearchRepositoryInternalImpl(ElasticsearchRestTemplate elasticsearchTemplate, ProductRepository repository) {
        this.elasticsearchTemplate = elasticsearchTemplate;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<Product> search(String query) {
            
        NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = new NativeSearchQuery(queryStringQuery(query)
                , QueryBuilders.termQuery("_routing", TenantContextHolder.getTenantContext()));
        nativeSearchQuery.setMaxResults(30);
        return search(nativeSearchQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public Stream<Product> search(Query query) {
        return elasticsearchTemplate.search(query, Product.class).map(SearchHit::getContent).stream();
    }

    @Override
    public void index(Product entity) {
        entity.setTenant(TenantContextHolder.getTenantContext());
        repository.findById(Long.valueOf(entity.getId())).ifPresent(t -> {
            entity.setElasticsearchId(entity.getTenant()+String.valueOf(entity.getId()));
            elasticsearchTemplate.save(t);
            });
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public Product save(Product entity) {
        entity.setTenant(TenantContextHolder.getTenantContext());
        entity.setElasticsearchId(entity.getTenant()+String.valueOf(entity.getId()));
        return elasticsearchTemplate.save(entity);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        elasticsearchTemplate.delete(TenantContextHolder.getTenantContext() + String.valueOf(id), Product.class);
    }
}
```